# Find a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am practicing for the exam. And would like to know whether my solution is right or wrong...

Find a basis for the subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$, where
$$
U = \{[a+2b−c,b−c,2a+b+c,a+b]  \mid \ a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}\}
$$

This is how I tried to solve this:
$$M = \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&2&-1&0\\
0&1&-1&0\\
2&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&0\\\end{array}\right]$$

And after row reducing it I got:

$$M = \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&-1&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\\end{array}\right]$$

And now I can see that the first column and second column have pivots so I interpret that $(1,0,2,1)$ and $(2,1,1,1)$ are the basis.

Is this correct or am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

No, you are wrong. Take $(1,0,2,1)$, for instance. It doesn't even *belong* to $U$ (after all, $1+0\neq0$).

What you can deduce from your computations is that\begin{align}U&=\left\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4\,\middle|\,a+c=0\wedge b-c=0\right\}\\&=\left\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4\,\middle|\,a=-c\wedge b=c\right\}\\&=\left\{(-c,c,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4\,\middle|\,c,d\in\mathbb R\right\}.\end{align}Therefore, a basis a $U$ is, for instance$$\{(-1,1,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}.$$

Note that there is an error in your computations. After the first three columns of $M$, there should be a fourth column, consisting only of $0$'s. This has to do with the fact that $d$ never appears in your equations.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in row reduce form?

Comment: @MariaMagdalena I can't answer that, because I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: I mean like in the same form as I tried to do (make them "vectors" and put into matrix and then row reduce the matrix).

Comment: @MariaMagdalena I understand now. Yes, you can, but in order to do that you have to start from a set of vectors that span the whole space, not from equations.